# How do I delete data using the primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-delete

Working on a small database project, and one of the requirements is to show how to delete data using the primary key. The exact statement is

- Show one delete statement that use a primary key to delete data

However, I can't figure out what the exact syntax for that would be. Could anyone show me a quick example?

Comment: Hint:  `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a basic [`delete` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Assuming table `mytable` and primary key `id`:

```
delete from mytable where id = 1
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason why it has to be id = 1?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WHERE clause In the delete statement to specify the conditions used to limit the number of rows that are deleted. For example, WHERE column_name = value. If a WHERE clause is not supplied, DELETE removes all the rows from the table.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;`

for example:

table name= person

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSMFi.png)

DELETE FROM persons WHERE id > 3;

deleted items which had id>3 and return me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Gt9.jpg)